# Cannot initialize the indexer process in magento 1.8

Tags: magento, product, reindex

I have installed below extension 
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/simple-configurable-products.html

After that can't indexing its getting following errors

"Cannot initialize the indexer process."

Please help me to sort out this issue.

Thanks
Yasmeen Tariq

Comment: which one creating the issue?

Comment: Thanks for reply. Unable to reindex the Product Price.

Answer (score 0):

First take a backup of  app `code / community / OrganicInternet / SimpleConfigurableProducts / Catalog / Model / Resource / Eav / Mysql4 / Product / Indexer / Price / Configurable.php` file.

[After that change the code to this one.](https://github.com/organicinternet/magento-configurable-simple/blob/4d9cbe81be103c12b2e478811281395748e32fc3/app/code/community/OrganicInternet/SimpleConfigurableProducts/Catalog/Model/Resource/Eav/Mysql4/Product/Indexer/Price/Configurable.php)